# Highcharts piechart is not drawing slices from JSON object

Tags: json, highcharts

For a client, my company is working on getting some data from AJAX-JSON calls into Highcharts.
The data is how many devices a client has active on his/her account.

The functions we use are:
**To get the JSON**

```
function getChartJSON(url){
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        async: false
    }).responseText;
}
```

**To create the chart**

```
function createPieChart(data, title){
    var json = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    var options = {
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
            renderTo: 'pie-container',
            type: 'pie'
        },
        title:{
            text: title
        },
        plotOptions:{
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                showInLegend: true
            },
        },
        series:[{data:json}]
    };

    $.each(data, function (i, point) {
        point.y = parseInt(point.data, 10);
    });

    new Highcharts.Chart(options);
}
```

Everything seems to be going fine, and the object is made, with the indices (indexes?) showing up for the types of slices (1, 2, 3, 4, 4+ devices active) but not the slices themselves.

The JSON being returned as a string is:

```
[
  {"name":"Single device registered","data":13},
  {"name":"Double device registered","data":0},
  {"name":"Triple device registered","data":2},
  {"name":"Quadruple device registered","data":0},
  {"name":"Quadruple-plus device registered","data":3}
]
```

What am I missing that does not allow for the slices to be drawn? I hope this is enough information for someone to help us figure this out, or at least replicate the issue at hand.

Comment: So the variable data in createPieChart() function is the json as a string?

Comment: @morganfree It is. The first rule in the function transforms it into a JSON array, though. Otherwise we'd get a chart with four pages of series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How ironic that as soon as I post an issue here, I find the answer. The error was in:

```
$.each(data, function (i, point) {
    point.y = parseInt(point.data, 10);
});
```

The first parameter is 'data', but it should have been 'json'. It now works.